# How To Save Users and Their Books (and Progress) Using Loopback 2.x?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, loopbackjs, loopback

let's say I have a user model and the user read many books (another model). so far so good. now I also want to save the user's progress percentage for each book he's reading. something like:

```
myBooks: [
{
  book: ObjectId: hj123bkj123,
  progress: 12%
},
{
  book: ObjectId: hj123bkj124,
  progress: 32%
},
...
]
```

I've tried using a through model with an extra property to save the progress and it works but it wont let me add books to a user and set the percentage through the user model (with one call) and I cant get all the user's books (and progress) through the user model either (with one call).

I can post my current configuration if needed...

any ideas?
Thanks!

Comment: It's better you show more about relationship config and models

Answer (score 0):

> Suppose your `through` model name is `BookProgress`

```
{
  "name": "BookProgress",
  "base": "PersistedModel",
  "idInjection": true,
  "options": {
      "validateUpsert": true
   },
  "properties": {
       "progress": {
       "type": "number",
       "required": true
   }
 },
 "relations": {
     "user": {
        "type": "belongsTo",
         "model": "User",
        "foreignKey": ""
     },
     "book": {
        "type": "belongsTo",
        "model": "Book",
        "foreignKey": ""
     }
 },
 ....
 ....
}
```

**There are two ways to fetch books and progress in one call.**

```
//Call using `BookProgress` `find` method with `include` of books
var userId = "123456785";
BookProgress.find({ where: {userId: userId}, include: ['books'] },
 function(err, bookProgress){
     if(!err){
        //Your book data along with progress in one call
     }
 });


 //Another way is to create Remote Method for each fetch and save method.  
 User.getBooks = function(userId, callback) {  
    //fetch user and progress along with the book data   
 }

 User.remoteMethod('getBooks', {
   accepts: {arg: 'userId', type: 'string'},
   returns: {arg: 'user', type: 'user', root: true}
  });
```

**For more info:**http://loopback.io/doc/en/lb3/Remote-methods.html